# Concepts of GraphQL and Relay

Tags: node.js, go, reactjs, graphql, relay

I am trying to build a `GraphQL endpoints` in `golang`.

I have been following these blogs [Learn Golang + GraphQL + Relay #1](https://wehavefaces.net/learn-golang-graphql-relay-1-e59ea174a902?gi=daa40a387844) for implementation of `graphQl` in `golang` and I have successfully built simple endpoints of `GraphQL`.

There are few concepts that are still unclear to me as how can I build a `pagination` endpoints using `graphQl`,
 Also methods like

```
//How to build endpoints for fetching data from this query
friends.first(1){
   cursor,
   node {
      name
   }
}

//or this query
friends.last(1){
   cursor,
   node {
      name
   }
}
```

[image: Introducing Relay and GraphQL]

As, I am from `Angular` Background this `Relay` concept are still very confusing to me. How relay works in facilitating the communication between clients and server.

Please provide some example using Node or anything which make these concepts more clear

Comment: Paginations are not part of GraphQL specs but it is part of the Relay library as [Connections](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-connections.html). You can implement paginations without Relay by defining input arguments for your GraphQL objects. Btw, the example GraphQL query you have seems a bit wonky. It should be `friends(first: 1) { cursor, node { name} }` where `friends` object accepts `first` input argument of type GraphQLInt. I will try to find time to create an example for pagination for `graphql-go`, seems like it would be very useful for a lot of people.

Comment: I've elaborated on my comments here https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql/issues/120

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pagination is never an easy question and not one explicitly solved by GraphQL. GraphQL provides a data fetching framework, how that framework is used to do things (like pagination) is up to the developer.

The [Relay](http://facebook.github.io/relay/) team has attempted to standardize pagination with the cursor connection [specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm) for GraphQL. The cursor connection specification is not unique to Relay and can be used with Angular, the main goal of the specification is to provide a standardized way to work with large collections from a GraphQL server. The main thing to note about this specification is that with every object there is an associated cursor. This associated cursor allows the client to resume pagination from any point in the collection.

If you are interested in implementing the Relay specification I encourage you to read Sashko Stubailo's [Understanding pagination: REST, GraphQL, and Relay](https://medium.com/apollo-stack/understanding-pagination-rest-graphql-and-relay-b10f835549e7#.niuznjno2) where he explains the motivation behind the Relay connection specification and explains how to implement it.

To see the connection specification in action, take a look at the example [SWAPI GraphQL API](http://graphql-swapi.parseapp.com/?query=%7B%0A%20%20allPeople(first%3A%205)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20people%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20gender%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hairColor%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) which implements the Relay specification in GraphQL. I encourage you to open the documentation window and browse the `PeopleConnection`. Note how they implement both `edges` and `people` fields.

If cursor pagination is too complicated for you to use/implement, you could always expose a traditional limit/offset pagination for your GraphQL API. The interface would probably look something like this:

```
{
  friends(limit: 5, offset: 20) {
    name
  }
}
```

Finally, the query you provided is from a very early technical preview of GraphQL and does not actually conform to the specification ([source](https://astexplorer.net/#/PdNSt8KDmk)). A more appropriate query (as mentioned by Hafiz) would be:

```
{
  friends(first: 1) {
    cursor
    node {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

There are two great talks from React Europe 2015 that I also recommend you watch which talk more about GraphQL without Relay.

- [Nick Schrock & Dan Schafer - Creating a GraphQL Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gY48GW87Feo)
- [Lee Byron - Exploring GraphQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQLzZf34FJ8)